# Rails x FastCGI

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Should i stay out of rails if a client has a cheap hosting service with a provider that do not support mod_rails? Will rails + fast.cgi provide a good experience for a user or should I choose, in this scenario, php + my-favorite-framework as platform ?

Regards,

Victor

Comment: Just to get a glimpse of what you're trying to achieve with rails, could you share what's the php framework that you're also considering?

Comment: it's a simple timesheet application but the problem with fastcgi is it must spawn a process to process the cgi then other to call rails, that's why mod_rails is better. Php framework always CodeIgniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three clients on inexpensive hosting plans using FastCGI and have not run into any issues due to FastCGI itself. These are all low traffic sites where Mongrel was not necessary.

> Will rails + fast.cgi provide a good experience for a user

It all depends on what you're trying to do. If you're going to build a site where users will uploading and playing video then no FastCGI is not a good choice.

> or should I choose, in this scenario, php + my-favorite-framework as platform

You always choose the right tool for the job. Without any details on what you are trying to build I'm not sure anyone here will be able to tell you how to build it.

Answer (score 3):

Fastcgi should be fine. Though it has been generally recommended to host rails apps on a platform that you own. There are some pretty affordable virtual private servers out there that let you do this.

Comment: i agree but some clients has already a paid server and don't wanna change for another one. "if a client has a cheap hosting service with a provider"

Comment: I used fastcgi on Dreamhost for a little while (to host a python based app). It worked, but I think that most hosts (especially the overselling kind) will limit you.

Answer (score 2):

My experience on low end hosts was really really bad.  Constantly having my mongrel instances die inexplicably.  Since switching to a slice I have had zero problems running it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to avoid FastCGI.  I haven't used it myself but I've read enough horror stories about it to never want to.

If the hosting company is going to be completely responsible for managing the server instance and you can trust them to be the ones who will make sure the app is always up and running, then maybe it would work.  I doubt this is the case though, and if you don't own the servers I think you'll run into a lot of problems troubleshooting the all the weird bugs FastCGI will inevitably throw at you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about mod_rails: it's new and Rails sites were running fine before it turned up. It's nice to have, I'm sure, but not a necessity.

By the time you're looking to get [rails to scale](http://railscantscale.com/) to volumes that really need mod_rails, the site should be worth putting into an environment that runs it.